# How Does a Constant Member Function Work In This Form?

Tags: c++, constants

---

I was wondering exactly how a constant member functions works in this context...

Custom Array Class:

```
class Array
{
private:
    int m_size;
    int *m_ptr;

    // Utility function
    void set_size( int size ); // Set size of array

public:
    // Constructors
    Array( int array_size ); // Default constructor
    Array( const Array &copy_array ); // Copy constructor

    // Destructor
    ~Array() { delete [] m_ptr; };

    int get_size() const { return m_size; }; // Get size of array

    // Overloaded Operators
    const Array &operator=( const Array &rhs );
}


const Array &Array::operator=( const Array &rhs )
{
    if( this != &rhs )
    {
        if( this -> get_size() != rhs.get_size() )
        {
            delete [] m_ptr;
            set_size( rhs.get_size() );
            m_ptr = new int[ get_size() ];
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < get_size(); i++ )
        {
            this -> m_ptr[i] = rhs.m_ptr[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I was wondering how the overloaded '=' operator works with declaring the constant first? Because the member function does change the value of the current object. And if you were utilizing this function, you could change the value of the object after the assignment as long as the current object itself was not constant. So i was wondering what the point of declaring the function constant like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a certain school of thought saying that `operator=` should return a const reference, in order to prevent code like `(a = b) = c` from compiling. This point of view was more common in the early days of C++, because C disallows the construct and people wanted C++ to behave the same way. It's uncommon these days.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is either a typo or a design error. The return reference should be without the const qualifier.

```
Array &Array::operator=( const Array &rhs )
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't exactly see why you would do something like this. It was an example in book.

Comment: @anacy Very often books contain typos. It is difficult to test all examples that a book has before publishing it.